# Sdk manager error in Android?

Tags: android

When I open Eclipse,I got a message box having particular error. So I did uninstall the Android from **Android** folder in **LocalDisk C**. After I Reinstall the Eclipse and and Replugin the ADT ,at that time it ask about Eclipse restart.When Eclipse open after restart, I have seen the same message box below.

![Eclipse Error Message Box][2]

**How to solve this problem ?**

[image]

Comment: update your ADT PlugIN and android-sdk to latest versions

Comment: When I check for updates,n o more update were found ......... I did one thing ..I deleted the Android folder from the C drive .....after re plug in ADT.I didn't see the Android folder in C drive

Comment: download the latest android sdk.then configure the path of android sdk with eclipse.
ADT plugin will not automatically download the android-sdk

Comment: Are you updated latest version (ADT 20.0)?

Comment: At the time of configure ... I have to set the directory , is it the downloaded SDK installer_r_2010.exe file path.

I have one doubt also ... what is the RED marks on AVD SDK manager  ..I posted one more image  .please check it  on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Update your ADT Plugin Go to Help and click on Check for Updates and check below link for more information.

[Update ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: @Hari then click on help > install new software and follow steps from above link.

Comment: @Hari your adt plugin version is 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395?

Comment: no, don't uninstall eclipse only update your adt and then download sdk update from andrid SDK manager, if you have any query then tell me.

Comment: I am now downloading the SDK tools revision 20.0.3 because that need an update ... is it right

Comment: yes, it is right after completion of installation go to android sdk manager and install updates.